# Migradoc, PDFsharp How to plot a step function curve

Tags: c#, plot, charts, pdfsharp, migradoc

Does anyone know how to plot a curve with corners of 90° in a chart?
It has to look like the red line in the image below:

[image]

Comment: After a closer look at the MigraDoc Chart shape I doubt you can create those lines in one of its Series. Maybe you can draw them as pixels..

Comment: In R or Matlab the usual approach would be to plot an array of y-values onto an array of x-values and if two different y-values would have the same corresponding x-value one would get such a corner into the curve. I haven't figured it out yet how to do this with the Chart object.

Comment: Yes and in a MS Chart you would do the same. But I don't see how to do that with a MigraDoc Chart. But given its terrible 'documatation' I may well be missing it.